# MySQL Access denied from command connection

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

So I'm connecting to an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance. As part of my production script I do:

`mysql -u root -pmy-secret -e "source resetDb.sql;" >> lastRun.log`

This `resetDb.sql` has the queries to create and populate the database info. Then keep on going with the app.

The thing is that mysql is rejecting my access this way by throwing

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

But if I connect with `mysql -u root -p` and manually enter the password, it lets me into the console, so this let's me see the password is right.

I get this output on the server

`$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
$ uname -a
Linux ip-xx.xx.xx.xx 4.4.0-1038-aws #47-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 28 20:05:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've seen in another questions about flushing privileges and resetting the root password, but my password is correct so it did no good to me.

Anyone has a clue? The idea is to run the script to automatically setup the whole server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the URL script using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your password is using "special" characters that the command shell is interpreting. Watch out for these characters in passwords:

> $ & ! \ [ ] < > `

Enclose your password in a single quote for Linux: 'my_%PATH_problem&password'. For Windows use double quotes. You can also escape problem characters using the bakslash `\`

Comment: You got it just right. I had the '$'. Enclosing it on quotes was enough like `mysql -u root -p'my-$ecret' -e "select * from mysql;"`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to use some quotes around the password?
Try this:

```
mysql -u root -p"your_passord" -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

you can even put equals in it:

```
mysql --user="root" --password="your_passord" -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

And if you want something permanent it seems you can try [this](https://www.codementor.io/slaith/setting-a-root-password-on-mysql-in-silent-mode-in-ubuntu-y6do6ug2u)(never test it):

Comment: Tried this and double quotes didn't work, dunno why. But concept was right. Chose the other answer because it listed the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that your root password has a specific host restriction.

So if you run

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user;
```

You may see that root@localhost, root@127.0.0.1, and root@% all exist but have different passwords.

Comment: Tried this and root only existed on localhost. Fortunately I'm only using it from inside the server (localhost).